# Can someone clarify the eastern orthodox teaching "Temps Immobile" of Fr. Alexander Schmemann?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, eschatology, heaven, philosophy, time

I've been reading about Eastern Orthodox theology and one thing that caught my attention is the unusual view of time that some Eastern Orthodox theologians have, in particular Fr. Alexander Schmemann. Can someone please explain to me what he means by what happens after the ressurection when time is "perfected" and turned into an "eternal temporality" or the "temps Immobile?" Does he literally mean that time will freeze and that our experience in our resurrected bodies will be entirely immutable? Or is something else meant by that, as I've read an article saying that in eternity the distinction of past, present, and future will not be erased but "clarified" and "perfected." (I read this in an article about the EO theology of time called Chalice of Eternity that left me with more questions that answers) I genuinely can't make heads or tails of any of this.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Recall the physical properties of the transfigured body of the risen Christ, and apply them to the concept of time, instead of matter.

Comment: A simple [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=Schmemann+"Temps+Immobile") reveals it to be synonymous with the concept of [kairos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kairos)

Comment: What writing or recording of Fr. Schmemann are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at answering the question:

In general the God created time and He is not constrained by time. That means the God is able to see the entire "time" at once, the same way we can take a physical object and look at it from different angles. That doesn't mean that "time" is erased - God has a perfect outlook on time.

Humans have both animal nature (body, which is constrained by time) and spiritual nature. After one dies, only the spiritual part remains. It is possible that then we will also have some aspects of that "perfect" outlook on time as God when we are not burdened by physical bodies.

That also means without a body we are not able to change ourselves (because time is required for us to make changes in ourselves) and our last chance to make any decisions and turn our fate around will happen during the Final Judgement, when we will receive new bodies (see: Philippians 3:20-21).

Also my opinion as an additional comment:

I think answering such questions in a clear way is impossible, because: we would have to understand what exactly time is and how it works - and to do so we would have to be able to observe the time from a higher dimension (which is impossible for us - creating a mathematical model is not the same as an empirical understanding). Paul The Apostle had a clear glimpse of the afterlife / spiritual side of life (see: Corinthians) and tried to explain what he experienced using human words and terms and deemed that also was impossible ("Corinthians 2:13: We also speak these things, not in words taught by human wisdom, but in those taught by the Spirit, combining spiritual thoughts with spiritual words."). So all that  suggests we can debate what afterlife looks like (as Schmemann does), but in the end Bible suggests that we won't find answers to such questions (because our physical bodies do not have the tools and capabilities required to describe them), so most likely you won't find a clear explanation anywhere.

Comment: "and our last chance to make any decisions and turn our fate around will happen during the Final Judgement, when we will receive new bodies (see: Philippians 3:20-21)." No. Your will is fixed **exactly** at death. The final judgment will not change your will's orientation.